# When my fields change save button does not work.

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, force.com

[image]

System size field has lot of depended fields. When i select system size equal 2000L sub and fill out other information, when i click on the save button it will not save my data. I know something wrong with my fields. this only happen when I select system size equal 2000L sub. Does any body know why is that? Thanks

**Page 1**

```
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 6: System Configuration" collapsible="false" columns="2">
     <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.System_Size_SUB_2013__c}" required="true"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Quantity_SUB_2013__c}" required="true"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Heating_Type__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Stainless_Steel_Type__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Motor_Type__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Drive_Shaft__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.RTD__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Loadcell_Kits__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Display__c}"/>
     <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Cable_Management_Tree__c}"/>
 </apex:pageBlockSection>

 <apex:pageBlockButtons >
     <apex:commandButton value="Next Page" action="{!page2}"/>
 </apex:pageBlockButtons>
```

**Page 2**

```
<apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <div style="display:none;">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.System_Size_SUB_2013__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Heating_Type__c}" style="display:none;"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Motor_Type__c}"/>
            </div>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 7: Optional Section" collapsible="false" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Temperature_Control_Unit__c}"/>  
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Condenser_Options__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Mobile_stair_assembly__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Vent_Heater__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.BPC_Type__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Vent_Filter_Quantity__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 8: Available Services" collapsible="false" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Available_Services__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection> 

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 9:BPC's, Spare Parts, and Other Accessories (ONLY ITEMS LISTED WILL BE QUOTED)" collapsible="false" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Standard_SUB_BPC_QTY__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Custom_SUB_BPC_QTY__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Probe_Assemblies_QTY__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Heavy_Duty_Tubing_Clamps_QTY__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Autoclave_Tray_QTY__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Probe_Clips_QTY__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Autoclave_Tray_QTY__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Motor_Assemply_QTY__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Drive_Shaft_QTY__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Load_Cells_QTY__c}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.RTD_QTY__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection> 

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 10:ETO Request Form" collapsible="false" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.ETO_Request__c}" label="Does the above options meet your needs?"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section 11:Other" collapsible="false" columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Questions_or_Changes__c}" />
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Previous Page" action="{!page1}"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Save Page" action="{!save}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
```

**Extension**

```
public PageReference save() {
    // ApexPages.StandardController from constructor
    if(controller.save() == null) {
        return null;
    }
    PageReference ref = Page.pitu3;
    ref.getParameters().put('id', controller.getId());
    ref.setRedirect(true);
    return ref;
    }
```

Comment: what does the pitu3 page do, as far as i can see your command button save does nothing but pass the id of the page to pitu3.

Comment: add a rerender to the command button

Comment: @Rao Pitu3 page is my view page. I have all fields in page1 and page2 and a output fields.  When someone done filling all info in page 2, then click on the save, it will save all info and direct into view page.